# Change boolean value of ith input field ondelete button press in Reactive form

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to make a dynamic input field using a reactive form.In my project, First I am generating number of input fields as per **Names coming from API** and then I can also create new input field on and button press.With every input, there is a delete button.With that user can delete that particular field. I am successfully able to delete that field but now I need that fields  name value and its uuid(which I am getting from api with name) on delete button press.Currently I am getting this response while submit form.

```
isdelete: false
screenname: "first"
screenuuid: "25ef9fde-bd02-4225-8c64-9cc12bea523"
```

By default, isdelete is set to false on formsubmit, but when user deletes this screen, I want to change the boolean value of isdelete to true of that screen.I tried to change the boolean value when input field deletion but failed to do that.Onsubmit I am getting same response as mentioned above.Here is my code.

**Component.ts file**

```
export class ScreenmodalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() screendetails;
  personalForm : FormGroup;
  arrayItems: any = [];
  screenList: string;
  isDelete: boolean = false;

  constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal, private formbuilder: FormBuilder, private pagesService: PagesService, private utilService: UtilService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personalForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      other: this.formbuilder.array([ ])
    });
    // Api call
    this.pagesService.GetScreens('').then(res => {
      console.log('get screens api', res);
      for (let i = 0; i < res['data']['length']; i++) {
        this.arrayItems = res['data'][i]['name'] ;
        this.addanother(res['data'][i]['name'],res['data'][i]['screen_uuid'],this.isDelete);
      }
    }).catch(error => {
    this.utilService.showError('Something went wrong', 'Error');
    console.log('err is', error);
    });
  }


  addanother(data: any,uuid:any,isdelete:boolean = false):void {
    (<FormArray>this.personalForm.get('other')).push(this.addanotherForm(data,uuid,isdelete));
  }
  addanotherForm(data:any,uuid:any,isdelete:boolean): FormGroup{

    return this.formbuilder.group({
      screenname: [data],
      screenuuid: [uuid],
      isdelete:   [isdelete]
    });
  }

clear(i : number){ //this function removes input field
  console.log("dvdv"+i);
  (<FormArray>this.personalForm.get('other')).removeAt(i);
}

onSubmit(): void {
  console.log(this.personalForm.value);
}

closeModel() {
    this.activeModal.close();
  }
}
```

**Component.html file**

```
  <div class="custom_modal pb-3">
    <div class="modal-header border-0 p-1 pl-3 pr-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h3 class="m-0">Project: {{screendetails.name}}</h3>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="closeModel()">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body p-3">
      <div class="body_top d-flex justify-content-between mb-4 mt-2 align-items-center">
        <h3 class="title m-0">Add Screens</h3>
      </div>
      <form [formGroup]="personalForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div formArrayName="other" class="form-group" *ngFor="let other of personalForm.get('other').controls; let i = index" >
        <div [formGroupName] = "i">
      <div class="screen_row mb-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <label>Screen Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 pl-0 pl-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" formControlName="screenname" name="screenname" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pl-0 pl-sm-3">
              <button type="button" class="close" (click)="clear(i)">&times;</button> //delete button
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer border-0 d-table w-100">
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary float-left" (click)="addanother('',null,false)">Add New Screen</button>
        <div class="float-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn-primary mr-3" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onSubmit();">Apply</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn-primary cancle" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="closeModel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
  </div>
```

Please help me to change the boolean value of ith input field if it is deleted.Your small help will be appreciated .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first you need to update arrayItems correctly to maintains changes of screens.

```
for (let i = 0; i < res['data']['length']; i++) {
    this.arrayItems.push(res['data'][i]['name']);
    this.addanother(res['data'][i]['name'],res['data'][i]['screen_uuid'],this.isDelete);
}
```

Then in the clear function try update the particular isdelete value for screen in the arrayItems.

```
clear(i : number){ //this function removes input field
    console.log("delete item index:"+i);
    arrayItems[i]["isdelete"] = true;
    (this.personalForm.get('other') as FormArray).removeAt(i);
    // Try this if you want to update form value as well
    ((this.personalForm.get('other') as FormArray).at(i) as FormGroup).get("isdelete").setValue(true);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Harshana.I tried your code but nothing is changing .I am getting same form on submit .Also arrayitems is not related to my formgroup.Sorry I by mistakely kept that in my code.I am pushing value in this.addanother only

Comment: Following code hide only the deleted element and you will get the entire form values at the end. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqqg52

Comment: Thank you Harshan ,in clear() function the code you written is works perfectly fine .But If I use remove input field code line in that function then I am not getting that input field on submit.However the value is changing but do you have any suggestion for how to dont show ith input field on delete and also get all field values on submit

Comment: The code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqqg52 has the hide function and with submit function you get all elements in there.  <div class="screen_row mb-4" *ngIf="!personalForm.value.other[i].isdelete">

Comment: Thank you so much Harshana.It is working exaclty as I wanted .I was trying to solve this issue from so many hours. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome I am so happy I was able to help you :)